# IBM Worklight: Integrating server generated pages in app

Tags: android, iframe, webview, ibm-mobilefirst

I am working with [Worklight tutorial - Integrating server-generated pages in hybrid applications](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/09_06_Integrating_server_generated_pages_in_Worklight_applications.pdf) and have a few questions would like to ask:

1. I can use `<iframe src="http://m.ibm.com" />` to embed the remote webpage in local HTML. Apart from there are some additional APIs which can control the WebView (e.g. set if JavaScript is enabled, clear history, etc). Is there any other benefit to use the WebViewOverlayPlugin over iframe?
2. I have tried to add

   webViewOverlay.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

in WebViewOverlaySample.java to enable to zoom control in WebView. However, the zoom control is not displayed. When I create a native Android app and add the zoom control to the WebView, it can be displayed successfully.
(Environment details: Android 4.1.1, Samsung Galaxy 3, API 14)

1. Is it possible to interact with the hybrid app in remote page? (By custom URL scheme?)

Answer (score 1):

iframe doesn't work so well in mobile browsers. There are many reports of unexpected behaviors on both iPhone and Android.

However if you use Worklight 5.0.6 and above, you may be able to use [Cordova's InAppBrowser](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser) to avoid having to code it in the native view directly.